# Flutter Sign out crash the application

Tags: flutter

In my menu, I have a log out call. It is not working like I want. The log out is active as when I start the application I must log in again. But the application does not display the login screen. The application crash and I am getting a lost connection to device.

I have done some research, but did not find the solution. Please, can you help? Thank you.

```
  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    leading: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                        minWidth: iconSize,
                        minHeight: iconSize,
                        maxWidth: iconSize,
                        maxHeight: iconSize,
                      ), //child: Image.asset('assets/icons/someday.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                    title: Transform(transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                        distanceEntreTextAndIcon, alignementTextWithIcon, 0.0),
                      child: const Text('Log Out'),
                    ),
                    onTap: ()  {
                      try {

                        FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginSignupScreen()), (
                            route) => false));

                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e.toString());
                        return;
                      }
                    }
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
///you don't need .of(context) not unless you are in a stateless widget like showDialog
onTap:(){
 Navigator.of(context).pop();
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginSignupScreen()), (
        route) => false));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but I am getting the same result. The application crashs.

Comment: Please share the crush error code

Comment: Lost connection to device. It is the only thing I am getting

Comment: Is it possible that you could share more code? Coz I don't know if it's hapening on a button or dialogbox

Comment: I have updated the code. It is in a Drawer Menu.

Comment: What version of Firebase auth are you using?

Comment: firebase_auth: ^4.1.0